# How do I query SQL Browser Service from Java?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sqlbrowser

This might be a basic question, but I tried googling it and couldn't find an answer.

I need to make a list of all the SQL Servers on a network. This is very easy to do using the .NET framework (System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator), but is there also a relatively simple way to do this in java as well? While I was doing my research, I came across the possibility of listening in at different ports, but that seemed un-user friendly.

I've been told to use SQL Browser Service, but a) I couldn't find any information on how to call that from java, and b) does this service get automatically downloaded when you download SQL Server? Can I assume that every computer on the network I'm searching has access to this browser service?  And if not, does that make a difference to my code?

Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SQLBrowseConnect function from ODBC API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlsrvenumerator.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can call COM components from java (with suitably crafted IDL), so you could use [DMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301940.aspx) or [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) (depending on your SQL Server version)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the command line's `osql -L` command to list all the servers on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it pretty easy to find all SQL services (assuming appropriate level of perms) by enumerating the Windows services on servers using WMI. This "catches" different SQL Server suite- services like Reporting Services and Analysis Services that are not the relational engine, plus services that are not running at the moment. I use this for license auditing, via PowerShell. So, if that seems useful, it's a matter of how to call WMI from Java. This dude: http://www.vijaykandy.com/archives/121 made a list of some options.